# How to return a sorted array without storying it (immutability introduction)?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, immutability

I have a dictionary that I project onto a list, which I sort. After that, I return the result. However, I'd like to know if it's possible (and if so - how) to return the sorted array without storing it first.

```
List<SomeType> thingies = dictionary.Select(element => element.Value).ToList();
thingies.Sort((the, thing) => the.Id.CompareTo(thing.Id));
return thingies;
```

The compiler nags that I can't put a *void* type as *List* type, which is understandable. But is it possible to make *Sort* spit out a new list to be returned (without polymorphism). Something along the lines of this.

```
  return dictionary.Select(element => element.Value)
    .ToList()
    .Sort((the, thing) => { ... });
```

Comment: are you looking for something like `return  dictionary.Select(element => element.Value.OrderBy(r=> r.Id).ToArray()).ToList();` ?

Comment: Side note: consider providing exact message for "nags that I can't put a void type as List type".

Comment: Isn't `dictionary.Select(element => element.Value)` the same as [`dictionary.Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Can you also clarify how "not storing" (assuming not declaring local variable?) is related to "immutability"?

Comment: @Habib Post it as a reply so I can accept the answer.   :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Nags: can't covert type void to List.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  *dic.Select=dic.Values* Don't know. I can try (the syntax's going to be much nicer if it works).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Immutable objects can't be altered, hence will be spitting out a new object with the changes introduced. Please view the examples code samples to show the storing. I'm using a temporary variable for sorting. Then returning it.

Comment: Why would you care about local list object to be modified by `Sort`? (I assume you are looking for `dictionary` to not modified in the sample). All versions of the code in the answers create local copy in some sort of list, sort and than return it...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I prefer to use the *return EXPRESSION* syntax, instead of *do-this, do-that THEN return results*. It's cleaner and easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: I see - so there was nothing related to immutable data structures, just your preference to use chained calls. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes. Or - to be precise - the **main** reason for asking was, as you so eloquently pointed out, my preference to using chained calls. However, that requires that the structured are immutable if the *return* is to be happen "in a single swing", so there **is** a relation to immutability but it's weak, at best. Sorry if I mentioned it in a confusing way.   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
return dictionary.Select(element 
  => element.Value.OrderBy(r=> r.Id).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

This will return an ordered List of value, without modifying the original `Array`.